# Setting receive_payment_on flag for employment applicants

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails

I would like to refactor this block, it looks clunky:

```
# refactor me
receive_payment_on = false
config[:sections].each do |section|
  if section[:applicants]
    section[:applicants][:sections].each do |app_sec|
      if app_sec[:employment] && app_sec[:employment][:receive_payment_on]
        receive_payment_on = true
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put your code into a method. So you get rid of the temporary variable, its cleaner and you can leave your method with a return as soon as you find the first true. (A break to leave the loop will have the same effect.)

In addition to that I'm a big friend of guard conditions. Invert `if section[:applicants] ... end` to `if !section[:applicants] next`, so you have one nesting level less.

```
...
config[:sections].each do |section|
   if !section[:applicants] next
   section[:applicants][:sections].each do |app_sec|
       if app_sec[:employment] && app_sec[:employment][:receive_payment_on]
           return true
       end
   end
end
return false
```

Comment: thanks for the awnser but i ended up using

Comment: receive_payment_on = true if config[:sections].join.include? 'next_paid_on'

Answer (score 2):

Don't use a for-loop (`each`), that's how you'd do it in language like C, in Ruby we have handy functional abstractions (or can build them if not present) like [Enumerable#any?](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-any-3F):

```
receive_payment_on = config[:sections].any? do |section|
  if section[:applicants]
    section[:applicants][:sections].any? do |app_sec|
      app_sec[:employment] && app_sec[:employment][:receive_payment_on]
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

how about using modifiers

```
receive_payment_on = config[:sections].any? do |section|
    section[:applicants][:sections].any? do |app_sec|
      app_sec[:employment] ? app_sec[:employment][:receive_payment_on] : false 
    end if section[:applicants]
end
```

(based on tokland's answer)